# Spring OAuth2.0 passing query parameters to login page

Tags: spring, authentication, oauth-2.0

Problem:  I make a request that requires authentication.  OAuth server will save the original request and redirect to "/login".  I need to pass a query parameter from the original request to the login form (I need this before the form is submitted in order to filter to the correct AuthenticationProvider).

Trying to filter on `super(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/login", "GET"));` is too late.  The ServletRequest is already a redirect to login.  Therefore, I tried to create a custom auth entry point which extended `LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint`.  I simply did an Override on `determineUrlToUseForThisRequest` to append my query from the original request.  This idea worked for the URL's sake, but unfortunately Spring's /login page does not show up unless the URL is exactly "/login".

Any idea on how to work around this would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT/Update**
This is not yet tested but — if I use a custom `AuthenticationEntryPoint` I can redirect to a custom login page endpoint. This endpoint would take in a `@RequestParam`and be put into a hidden field on the login form. Then I can POST with that new field added to `WebAuthenticationDetailsSource`. From here, my POST filter should correctly choose a provider.

Comment: I forgot to mention, I am trying to avoid this being an extra field in the form.  I realize I can use a `CustomWebAuthenticationDetailsSource` but I want this to be transparent to the user.  thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I configured my setup as stated above in my Edit/Update.  It works.
1) I configured a `CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint`
2) Did a `@Override protected String determineUrlToUseForThisRequest()`
to build my login string with a query parameter passed in from client's request.
3) LoginController does this

```
@GetMapping("/login")
public ModelAndView showCustomLoginForm(@Valid @RequestParam(value = "realm_name", required=false) final String realmName) {
    CustomLoginForm form = new CustomLoginForm(realmName);
    return new ModelAndView(CUSTOM_LOGIN_FORM_VIEW, CUSTOM_LOGIN_FORM_MODEL, form);
}
```

where realm_name is my hidden field in the form that I need upon POST.